# Making Dynatree <li> unclickable

Tags: jquery, jquery-dynatree

So, I've been using dynatree (http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html) with checkboxes for the listing of my data. Apparently, I wanted to remove the functionality that will let the checkboxes be clicked if `<li>` tag has been clicked. Been researching for this but did not yield to any solution.

Comment: Did you try css `pointer-events: none` ?

Comment: Just note that `pointer-events: none` doesn't have the greatest cross-browser support.

Comment: @jellyfication Jonathan is right, check browser support here: http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20pointer-event

Comment: @Tony, Yeah, Sadly, I needed to implement it on IE

Comment: @jellyfication Ok, what about `$("#checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little snippet should do what you want:

```
$("#my-div").dynatree({
  checkbox: true,
  onActivate: function (node) {
      node.data.unselectable = true;
  },          
});
```